# Java String split code, doesn't separate the words

Tags: java, regex, string

The following String split code in Java 11, isn't working as I expect it to.

```
String[] s = " 75 12, 241 123, 123 123 123, 123 123 123.".split(" ");
```

should give me

```
["75", "12,", "241" ...]
```

But it just returns the original string. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the non working code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] s = " 75 12, 241 123, 123 123 123, 123 123 123.".split("\\s");
        String[] s1 = "This is a test string., j".split(" ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s) + s.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s1) + s1.length);
    }
}
```

Here is the output (in IntelliJ idea)

```
[ 75 12, 241 123, 123 123 123, 123 123 123.] (length: 1)
[This, is, a, test, string.,, j] (length: 6)
```

The IDE screenshot is attached, because people haven't been able to replicate this, and I'm not sure if this result because of wrong code or some IDE quirk. If it's an IDE problem, then at this point I'm unaware of what config files/settings to share. I'll be happy to do so if requested.

[image]

This was a learning experience for me. As answered by Audrius Meskauskas, there is a possibility of regex not matching because of weird characters in the supplied string. Here is a test from regex101 site.

[image]

The first line was pasted to the site from the IDE and none of the spaces match. But that isn't so for the second line which was typed directly in the site. Similarly in the original code, I was pasting the test case into the console from the description section on the side, which may have the observed bug.

The question is from one of the Java track projects in Jetbrains academy. My mistake was, instead of typing out the test case into my code, I was just copy pasting from the problem description in the side panel. This might have resulted in some characters getting copied that the regex pattern couldn’t catch.

Comment: Can't reproduce. `" 75 12, 241 123, 123 123 123, 123 123 123.".split(" ")` produces `String[11] { "", "75", "12,", "241", "123,", "123", "123", "123,", "123", "123", "123." }` without any change in code.

Comment: Your code should work fine! I testing it at [this online platform](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/) and it works fine.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, the following line is printed `|75|12,|241|123,|123|123|123,|123|123|123.|`, thus voting to close

Comment: 1) Rather than posting screenshots, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as part of your question that we can copy into a fill and run for ourselves.  (You have been around here long enough that you **should** already know this!!)  2) Try compiling and running the application from the command prompt.

Comment: @StephenC I posted the screenshot because, as you can see in the earlier comments, people aren't able to reproduce my error. The code itself has only 1 relevant line, so I don't see what you're problem is.

Comment: Nobody is doubting that you are having a problem.  But posting a screenshot doesn't help us to reproduce it.  For all we know it could be due to some weirdness that is not apparent in the screenshot; e.g. strange whitespace characters ... or a misconfigured IDE.  We can't reproduce your problem ... without a minimal reproducible example.  People have said that they have typed in your one line of code and it has run correctly.  If you want help the onus is on >>you<< to provide other people with a way to examine your evidence.  A screenshot doesn't help.  Clearly.

Comment: @StephenC the screenshot is the evidence. I don't know which configuration files one might need to resolve this, so I provided a screenshot. If you are aware of any other information that will help, then I'd be grateful if you mention that and save us both this unpleasantness. Anyways, the example has been added to the question. Thanks.

Comment: *"I'd be grateful if you mention that and save us both this unpleasantness"*  - **A minimal reproducible example.**  There is nothing to examine in a screenshot.  It is evidence that something is not working, but not of why it is not

Comment: If I knew why it isn't working, then why in the world would I post the question here?

Comment: I ran the example class in your question.  The class prints the length of the array differently.  It is not just a different length value.  Run it for yourself and you will see.  Therefore, I don't accept this as a valid minrep for your problem.  On reflection, I don't think that it is plausible that this is an IDE "quirk".  I also don't think it is plausible that is a bug in the Java compiler, or `String.split`, etc.  The behavior is actually in the code you are running.  I think it can only be due to weird characters in your *real* source code file ... which you have not  shared.

Comment: I have better things to do than engage in this. I don't believe you have actually run the code. The screenshot I gave along with the code sample clearly shows everything that is relevant and the error itself clearly. I don't have the time or energy to fabricate an image that fakes a single file program in Java. Throughout this conversation you have acted in extremely bad faith and it's ridiculous why you continue to do so. Please find better things to do than being abusive to other developers in your free time.

Comment: I have actually run the code.  The output is `java Main 
[, 75, 12,, 241, 123,, 123, 123, 123,, 123, 123, 123.]11
[This, is, a, test, string.,, j]6`   You said that Intellij output is `[ 75 12, 241 123, 123 123 123, 123 123 123.] (length: 1)
[This, is, a, test, string.,, j] (length: 6)`.   Please explain how the code in the Question can *possibly* output the text "length".

Comment: How did you actually create the code that is in the Question?  Did you type it in again?  Did you copy and paste it?  Are you sure that your copy and paste is preserving any weird whitespace?

Comment: You're still at it? @StephenC , you should look at the screenshot if you're confused. That will help you understand the problem much better, I assure you. Hint (since you seem to be angry about something and aren't capable of thinking clearly in your current state, at the very least): look at the placement of the "|" character in the console output in the screenshot. Also, take another look at the question. I have updated it with more screenshots, that you might like.

Comment: I am not in the slightest bit angry.  You are the one who is making all sorts of wild accusations.  Review your comments for examples; e.g. search for words like "bad faith", "abusive", "incapable of thinking", "ridiculous", "unpleasantness".

Comment: For what it is worth, the only reason I am continuing with this is to get you to acknowledge that 1) your claimed minrep was nothing of the kind and 2) a proper minrep was possible, and *would* have allowed people to give you a definite answer.  And the way you create the minrep would simply to be to copy-and-paste the failing code into your question ... preserving all of the funky characters in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
" 75 12, 241 123, 123 123 123, 123 123 123.".split(" ")
```

should definitely work and there is nothing wrong with it.

One of the possible reasons is that the character between quotes that you see as a space is not actually a single space (ASCII 0x20, I mean). It can be two spaces instead, or a tab. It can also be something more exotic if the code is copy-pasted from some web page or other "rich text" document. Then it may be unusual characters around, like non breakable space, for instance.

I never observed problems with whitespace myself but if such things happen, I would suggest to use the more generic `\s+` construct (any whitespace, one or more times) or use Unicode instead (`\u0020` is the regular space).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
String[] stringArr = " 75 12, 241 123, 123 123 123, 123 123 123.".split("\\s+");
```

\\s matches a single White Space and \\s+ matches one or more white spaces

Comment: From the examples from `String.split`, `" "` should be enough. I'm asking if this is some IDE quirk I'm missing.

Comment: They may not be just space characters; they could be tabs spaces